# Compress an image with rest api

Tags: laravel, typescript, ionic3

Have a big problem here. I have 7000 data and image  to call from my laravel server side. And the image file is about 1mb and the image is in the local assets laravel. I have no problem to display the picture and the data. But it takes so long and laggy to perform. Ive tried a lot of suggestion and not giving me solution. Can you all please help me. And sorry for my bad english

Note : since the user doesnt wanna duplicate image with save intervention. And i put some code in routes.

Route::get('getpicture/{id}/{namefile}, function($id, $namefile){
$img = Image::make(public_path('img/'.$id.'/'.$namefile.''))->resize(80,80)->response('data-url');
Return $img;
});

But it still laggy. I think its because 1 function returning 1 image.

Any solution again?

Comment: So what exactly have you tried?

Comment: It looks like for your situation is pretty nice to have images in some Cloud DB.
Other solution can be resizing images and return to user the lower quality/smaller image with library like that : http://image.intervention.io/

Comment: For now im using intervention . Im putting in the route::get('getpicture/{public}/{id}/{name_file}',function($public, $id, $namefile){ $img = img::make(public_path('img/'.$id.'/'.$namefile.'))->resize(300,200)->response('data-url'))}) since the user user doesnt wanna save 2 picture at the same name. Im using this. And my img src="http://127.0.01:8000/getpicture/{{content.id}}/{content.namefile}}". And it takes so long to load the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not resize an image on the fly for each request as it resource consuming and may be the cause of that long delay.

Resize the image on upload or at least store the resized one the first request so every subsequent request will be faster as the image won't have to be processed again.

Comment: So i have to make a function to call all the image in client side? Or make another function in laravel server side to compress all image?

Comment: Create a function on laravel side to compress all images or keep your current setup but save the image after resizing it, and check if the resized image exists: if so serve the resized image, if not resize it and save it. That way it is resized only on the first request.

Comment: Thx lucas for your advice. i actually save base64 image to the DB with intervention. And call it wherever i want.

Comment: Althought storing images in db might appear as a good solution (easier maintenance and backups) it is consired to be a bad practice. You should store images on disk and just store the path in the db, it's pretty easy with Laravel and packages are here to help (eg: spatie/laravel-medialibrary).

Comment: Ya it takes some times to request the APi. laravel medialibrary means that all images stores to the local of my laravel server?

Comment: Yes, laravel medialibrary will store imgs on your app local storage